# Google Drive SDK/API gapi can't load auth on IIS server(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

Im trying to get the Google Drive Picker using Javascript working inside my form but my gapi object won't load "auth".

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined
```

My code works in my test-environment(http-server), but as soon as I implement it in my work-environment(IIS7 server) Im returned with the error above. One thing that might be worth noting is that my test-environment runs a .html file while the work-environment runs a .php file, they're both rendered as html in the end so im not sure if this would be an issue.

If someone could help me by telling me as to where I go wrong that'd be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
var googlebtn = document.getElementById("GoogleBtn");

function onApiLoad(){

    gapi.load('auth',{'callback':onAuthApiLoad});

    gapi.load('picker'); 
}

function onAuthApiLoad(){

    window.gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id':'583082286729',
        'scope':['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    },handleAuthResult);
} 
var oauthToken;

function handleAuthResult(authResult){
    if(authResult && !authResult.error){
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        console.log(oauthToken);
        createPicker();
    }
}

function createPicker(){    
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())                
        .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
        .setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyAe3mAw6BvQzkpbTWxns4UFAbATN_1euQM')
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
}

function pickerCallback(data) {

    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED)       {
      var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
      var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];

    }
    if(data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.CANCEL){

    }

  }


googlebtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

onApiLoad();

});
```

Comment: window.gapi.auth is undefined, did you include google api js scripts?

Comment: @SilentTremor
Yes, both these are loaded: apis.google.com/js/client.js and google.com/jsapi?key= xxxx

Comment: @SilenTremor They're also shown as OK in the Network tab in Google DevTools, loaded in before my googledrive code.

Comment: copy paste this code in console, and call manually  onApiLoad();

Comment: Still undefined, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't loading the api correctly(the reason my gapi object was missing functions), fixed by adding the `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>` in the header.